# Array fetch using vue.js & js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

New to vue & js. Trying to create a simple login authentication. 
The 'if' works for array [0] but not for [1][2][3] etc. I want it to check all arrays for a match.

Here is my code:

Any help will be appreciated.

````
var app1 = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        name: null,
        password: null,
        users: [],
    },
    mounted() {
        this.users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
            if (this.name == this.users[0].text && this.password == this.users[0].password) {
                alert("success");

            }
             alert("failed");
        }

    }

}); ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I hope you're doing this as a practice, just for yourself, or don't really care about security. User credentials should always be checked server-side.

That being said, you can loop over the users until you find one that matches *(with a* `for` *loop, for example)*, or simply use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
login() {
  var correspondingUser = this.users.find(u => this.name == u.text && this.password == u.password);
  if (correspondingUser) { alert('Welcome, ' + correspondingUser.text); }
  else { alert('failed'); }
}
```